# Dropping some row from a Table with If condition

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I have to drop the rows of a table only when the element in the first coloumn of the row satisfies multiple condition.

The table:

```
tab = Table[{i, i^2}, {i, 1, 10}]
{{1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 49}, {8, 64}, {9, 81}, {10, 100}}
```

What i tried:

```
dim = Dimensions[tab][[1]]
For[i = dim, i > 0, i--,
 If[tab[[i, 1]] > 8||tab[[i, 1]] < 2,
  tab = Drop[tab, i, None]]]
```

What it does:

```
tab
 {}
```

What i expect

```
tab
{{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 49}, {8, 64}}
```

Comment: Try `Select[Table[{i, i^2}, {i, 1, 10}], First[#] <= 8 &]`.

Comment: Although, using `For` is generally discouraged; if you are going to use it in this instance, learn the syntax for `Drop`. Note that `tab = Drop[tab, i]` drops multiple rows, i.e., the first `i` rows. You want `tab = Drop[tab, {i}]` which will just drop row `i`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
DeleteCases[tab, _?(#[[1]] < 2 || #[[1]] > 8 &)]
```

Answer (score 6):

Select the wanted:

```
f1 = Function[i, {i, i^2}]
tab = Table[f1[i], {i, 1, 10}]
keep = Function[i, 9 > i > 1] (* the selection predicate *)
Select[tab, keep@*First]
```

Or, don't create the unwanted:

```
f2 = Function[i, If[keep[i], {i, i^2}, Nothing]]
Table[f2[i], {i, 10}]
```

Answer (score 4):

You *could* also use `Except` with `Cases`...

```
Cases[tab,Except[{a_,b_}/;a>8||a<2]]
```

> {{2,4},{3,9},{4,16},{5,25},{6,36},{7,49},{8,64}}

Answer (score 1):

The OP wants to drop the rows of a table only when the values in the first column satisfy multiple conditions, specifically (as an example) when the values in the first column are less than 2 and greater than 8.

Two powerful functions that may be useful here are [Select](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select.html) and [Pick](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick.html)

**Select**

As [J. M.'s technical difficulties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-s-technical-difficulties) neatly showed in a comment, and in an astute criticism of my original post, `Select` may be used in the following manner to solve the problem:

```
Select[tab, 2 <= First[#] <= 8 &]
```

> {{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 49}, {8, 64}}

Alternatively (again due to [J. M.'s technical difficulties](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m-s-technical-difficulties)), [Between](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Between.html) may be used to avoid slots completely:

```
Select[tab, Between[{2, 8}] @* First]
```

> {{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 49}, {8, 64}}

Two other variants with `Select` (from original post):

```
Select[tab, First[#]>=2 && First[#] <= 8 &]
```

and:

```
Select[tab, !(First[#]<2 || First[#] > 8) &]
```

**Pick**

Maybe something like the following:

```
Pick[tab,Between[{2, 8}]/@tab[[All,1]]]
```

> {{2, 4}, {3, 9}, {4, 16}, {5, 25}, {6, 36}, {7, 49}, {8, 64}}

or (original answer):

```
Pick[tab,#>8 || #<2&/@tab[[All,1]],False]
```

**Comment**

As the above is not original and might even be considered obvious, I have made this answer a Community wiki.  Feel free to edit/append/delete as required. IMO we need to be careful that the obvious answer, and not just the more innovative and creative solutions, is included in posts such as this, for the benefit of future visitors to the site

Comment: (+1 of course.) Whenever possible, I prefer to write selection conditions of this kind in interval format: `Select[tab, 2 <= First[#] <= 8 &]`. In particular, using `Between[]` allows for writing a slot-free version: `Select[tab, Between[{2, 8}] @* First]`.